# Laravel 6 search function problems

Tags: php, search, laravel-6

I've been trying to get the search function for my application to work for more than a week now, have read all the articles, but I just can't figure it out.
I am working on a library application in Laravel 6, which is my first application ever.
I want to create a search function, where the user can search for titles of books that are in the library.
I have managed to write some code, but I can't get back any results.
What could be the problem?

BookController:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $books = DB::table('books')->where('title','like','%' .$search. '%')->paginate(5);
    return view('books/index',['books' => $books]);
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')


@section('title')
<title>Alle Bücher</title>
@section('content')
<style>
  .uper {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
</style>
<div class="uper">
  @if(session()->get('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('success') }}
  </div><br />
  @endif
  <div align="left">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>Books</h1>


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="get" role="search">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_method" placeholder="Search Title> <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Titel</td>
        <td colspan="2">Autor</td>
        <td>Jahr</td>
        <td colspan="2">Verlag</td>
        <td colspan="2">Genre</td>
        <td>Sprache</td>
        <td>ISBN</td>
        <td>Seitenzahl</td>
        <td>Ausgeliehen von:</td>
        <td colspan="2">Funktionen</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($books as $book)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$book->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$book->title}}</td>
        @foreach($book->authors as $author)
        <td>{{$author->name}}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>{{$book->year}}</td>
        @foreach($book->publishers as $publisher)
        <td>{{$publisher->name}}</td>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($book->genres as $genre)
        <td>{{$genre->name}}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>{{$book->language->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$book->isbn}}</td>
        <td>{{$book->pages}}</td>
        <td>{{$book->user->name}}</td>

        <td><a href="{{ route('books.edit', $book->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Bearbeiten</a></td>
        <td>
          <form action="{{ route('books.destroy', $book->id)}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Löschen</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    @endsection
```

Route:

```
Route::get('search','BookController@search')->name('search');
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="_method"` change name to search and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your blade file. Your input field name attribute is not the same as you are using in search function.
`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="_method" placeholder="Search Title> <span class="input-group-btn">`

should be

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Title> <span class="input-group-btn">`